# Using cmake in linux

Tags: linux, cmake

I don't like cmake. Now that that is said, here's the question;

1) How do I tweak the configuration using cmake? Using make all that is necessary is configure --help to get commands to setup configuration properly before running make, how is this done with cmake or is it even possible?

2) Using make I can create an installation package for my distribution using,
make DESTDIR=/directory/build/ install, and the files are installed to /directory/build then I easily go into /build and make the package for program installation and removal later on if necessary, but with cmake I see no way to do this and the program is unremovable.

I suppose there is a way to do these things I just haven't found them yet.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you've extracted some source package `project-1.0.0.tar.gz` which has created a directory with a similar name. When I use cmake, I typically create a directory called `build` in which the `.o` files etc will be stored, so as not to contaminate the source directory:

```
/home/user/project-1.0.0> mkdir build
/home/user/project-1.0.0> cd build
```

From that directory, I then execute ccmake (that's with two c's) which is the ncurses interface to the cmake configuration. Since you have to specify where the main CMakeLists.txt is, in this example the command would be

```
/home/user/project-1.0.0/build> ccmake ..
```

That starts the user interface which initially won't show anything.

Then you need to press 'c' (configure) to let cmake start figuring things out. When this is done, you should see several cmake variable names appear, together with their value. You probably won't need to change them, I typically only fill in the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable and set it to `release` (for more optimized compiler settings)

You'll need to press 'c' at least one more time (possibly more, depending on what the cmake script does), until all the `*` before the values of the variables are gone. Then, you can press 'g' to generate the makefiles.

When the makefiles are created, everything probably works as you expect. You can do `make`, `make install`, `make install DESTDIR=/my/new/dest/dir`.

Apart from the ncurses user interface, there also exists a Qt based user interface.